# RobotFrameWork: hit on a title of a link

Tags: robotframework

I made the tests so it hits on the ID of a link, however, the ID's are dynamic. So now i'd like to hit on the name of a link...

```
<a class="dxeHyperlink_Office2003O" id="ASPxMenu1" href="/Configuration/specimen.aspx">Omzetgroepen</a>
```

so how do I hit on the  **Omzetgroepen**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath, based on the title:

```
//a[text()="Omzetgroepen"]
```

The target:

```
//a[@href="/Configuration/specimen.aspx"]
```

Comment: Click Element  xpath://a[@href="specimen.aspx"]